# Support Vector Machine in WEKA multiple data types in input

Tags: svm, weka

I've been trying to implement SVM in Weka.I have one predictor that consists of different data types and of course one output column (target).I am given a list of product codes, dates, sales person's tax identification number

Example:   **INPUT**       **OUTPUT**
           1234        ProductCode
           2344        ProductCode
           3456        ProductCode
           Continues   ProductCode
           12/01/2013  Date
           08/05/2003  Date
           Continues   Date
           12345678    ID
           87654321    ID
           Continues   ID

When I prepare my arff file, I need to identfiy the type of my data such as below. My question is since my input contains both digits, strings and date, can i have multiple data types? What can replace XXXXs below?Thanks

@relation Classification

@attribute Input    XXXXXXXXXXX
@attribute output   {ProductCode,Date,ID}

@data

...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question can be found [here](https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+(stable+version)).

Weka attributes can be:

1. numeric
2. nominal (represented by an exhaustive list of possible values {one, two...}
3. string
4. date (following the date format specified at the above link)